# How to get a value from second element of a class with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

my html code:

```
        <select class="b_selectbox">
            <option value="0">Status</option>
        </select>

        <select class="b_selectbox">
            <option value="0">Type</option>
        </select>

        <select class="b_selectbox">
            <option value="0">Category</option>
        </select>
```

That's working for first element:

```
$(".b_selectbox option:first").text();
```

I am trying to get text "Type", here is what i tried so far:

```
 $(".b_selectbox option:first").text()[1]; // result: "t" probably second letter from "Status"

$(".b_selectbox option:first")[1].text(); // not working either
```

Is there a solution without using each and id names ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Either

```
$('.b_selectbox option').eq(1).text();
```

if each select element has only one option (makes a `select` unnecessary?), or if you want to get the second of all options, or

```
$('.b_selectbox').eq(1).children('option').first().text();
```

if you want the text of the first `option` of the second `select` element.

For more information, see [`.eq()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: I don't get it why we should remove "option:first" ?

Comment: You mean with `$('.b_selectbox option').eq(1)`? If `option:first` will always select the first option in the set. It's the same as `$('.b_selectbox option').eq(0)`, it always selects the first element. You want the second one though, if you had `$('.b_selectbox option:first').eq(1)`, you'd get an empty jQuery element, because `$('.b_selectbox option:first')` is a set of only one element. See http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [:eq](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq) operator... Try,

```
$(".b_selectbox:eq(1) option:first").text()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/twdSA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".b_selectbox option:first").is(":selected").text() ?
```

Comment: pardon my french but what are you after ?